# Error in display checkbox input into table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this table to be display checkbox element that is clicked by user. But now if the user click the checkbox, it won't display anything.

```
<td ng-switch="user.scope">
   <span class="label label-primary" ng-switch-when="1">Admin</span>
   <span class="label label-primary" ng-switch-when="2">App</span>
   <span class="label label-primary" ng-switch-when="3">Redemption</span>
</td>
```

this is the checkbox element from my modal form.

```
<label for="scope">Scope</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.admin" name="scope[]" value="1"> Admin <br>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.app" name="scope[]" value="2"> App <br>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.redemption" name="scope[]" value="3"> Redemption <br>
```

And this is the javascript part.

```
$scope.users = [{username: "a", name:"b", password:"c", confirmpassword:"d", status:"0", scope:"1" }];

    $scope.addUser = function(user) {
        $dialog.open({
            showClose: false,
            closeByEscape: true,
            template: 'views/user/user-user-add.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function ($dialogScope) {
                $dialogScope.isLoading =false;
                $dialogScope.title = "New User";
                $dialogScope.user = {
                    username : "" ,
                    name : "",
                    password :"",
                    confirmpassword :"",
                    status : "",
                    scope : {},
                };

 $dialogScope.add = function() {
                    console.log($dialogScope.user);
                    $scope.users.push($dialogScope.user);
                    $dialogScope.closeThisDialog();
                }
```

Comment: You need to set the value of `user.scope` as either 1,2 or 3, you have it as an object

Comment: this is from the controller, but it don't display it in the table @ArunPJohny scope
:
Object
scope3
:
true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple selection you cannot use `ng-switch` since it only relies on the value of one expression, you need to check each expression, `user.scope.admin` etc and use ng-show.

Example:

```
<td>
   <span class="label label-primary" ng-show="user.scope.admin">Admin</span>
   <span class="label label-primary" ng-show="user.scope.app">App</span>
   <span class="label label-primary" ng-show="user.scope.redemption">Redemption</span>
</td>
```

Comment: gives me an error instead. checkbox cant choose. automatically click all

Comment: do you need to select only one? or multiple?

Comment: i need to do a multiple selection

Comment: do i need to change anything in javascript? as scope:"1" display nothing

Comment: @sue `user.scope: '1'` will not display anything, since user.scope is an object in your case; it has the properties `admin`, `app` and `redemption` and you are checking against those values. so you need to user `user.scope.app` etc